# Update all bindings in UserControl at once

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I need to update all the bindings on my UserControl when its visibility changes to Visible. Pretty much all my bindings are bound to the DataContext property of the user control so I'm trying to update the target of that binding:

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(this, UserControl.DataContextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

But I get `null` as the result of `GetBindingExpression(..)` method and I'm wondering if I'm using this wrong.

Also, is there any other good way to refresh all bindings on the control (which use DataContext as the source).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you *could* just re-assign the `DataContext`:

```
var dataContext = DataContext;
DataContext = null;
DataContext = dataContext;
```

FYI, resetting the property to its value (i.e.`DataContext = DataContext`) won't work.

Comment: OMG, you are a genius! Why, WHY haven't I thought of this?!

Thanks, this worked :)

Comment: Is there a more graceful WPF'y way of doing this? Shouldn't WPF support some sort of binding refresh mechanism?

Comment: The most delvish thing is that without the second line, the refresh doesn't happen. It appears no matter how you shuffle the DataContext property, nothing happens unless it is set to null. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase method on the wrong property.  You have to use it on the properties which are binding to the DataContext property, not the DataContext property itself.