# OnPropertyChanged with dictionary reference

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have XAML code like this

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

    <TextBox Text="{Binding A, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding B, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding C, Mode=OneWay}" />

</Grid>
```

and C# code with DataContext class

```
public class TableData : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Dictionary<string, object> SourceData = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "A", (double)55 }, { "B", (double)44 } };

    public double A { get { return (double)this["A"]; } set { this["A"] = value; } }
    public double B { get { return (double)this["B"]; } set { this["B"] = value; } }

    public double C { get { return this.A + this.B; } }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {

            return this.SourceData[key];

        }
        set
        {

            OnPropertyChanging(Binding.IndexerName);

            this.SourceData[key] = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName);

        }
    }

    #region INotify

    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    protected virtual event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    event PropertyChangingEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging
    {
        add { PropertyChanging += value; }
        remove { PropertyChanging -= value; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string Name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanging(string Name)
    {
        PropertyChanging?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(Name));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

This code above work fine with DataGrid, but no with TextBox. Problem is, when i change A or B property online, C property don't recalculate itself. **I don't want use this code:**

> {Binding [a]}

or private property like this

> private double _A { get; set; }
>
> private double A { get { return _A; } set { A = value;
>   OnPropertyChanged("A") } }

Because i have SourceData dictionary with data and i reference to property A from others code - warning works, if somebody type a wrong code. If i use Binding [A], that's works, fine, but don't work intellisense - obviously.

Is any way, to recalculate C property with no using OnPropertyChanged("C")?

Comment: Is the original problem to detect broken bindings at compile time?

Comment: Yes, and not prevent mistake from programmer input.

Comment: You can take look upon this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208011/detect-in-xaml-broken-bindings-already-at-compile-time

Answer (score 0):

> Is any way, to recalculate C property with no using OnPropertyChanged("C")?

No, there isn't. At least not from within the view model class. WPF listens to this event which means that you must raise it whenever you want to refresh the view.

But you could just call the `OnPropertyChanged` method in the setters of `A` and `B`:

```
public double A { get { return (double)this["A"]; } set { this["A"] = value; OnPropertyChanged("C"); } }
public double B { get { return (double)this["B"]; } set { this["B"] = value; OnPropertyChanged("C"); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

mm8 is right, you have to know the dependencies of the properties, then you can use them:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string[]> dependencyDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

static TableData()
{
dependencyDict.Add("A", new string[1]{"C"});
dependencyDict.Add("B", new string[1]{"C"});
}

Dictionary<string, string[]>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propNames)
    {
            if (propNames!=null && PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                foreach (var propName in propNames)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
                }
            }
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {

            return this.SourceData[key];

        }
        set
        {

            OnPropertyChanging(Binding.IndexerName);

            this.SourceData[key] = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName);
            OnPropertyChanged(dependencyDict[key]);

        }
    }
```

Other way would be reset a DataContext for your "parent" control, which contains all other controls with binding to calculated properties:   [Update all bindings in UserControl at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794370/update-all-bindings-in-usercontrol-at-once)

Comment: Yes, good idea, but imagine this. I have twenty and more tables with this code, each linked together (for example, one property reference to another from different class and different table using something math). If i forget one dependency to property, it's big problem. I can use OnPropertyChanged("") for each value setting, but this call have slow effect to wpf window (of course with using large data and tables, which i do)